# CDN options for image resizing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, image-manipulation, cdn

Background:

I working on an application on Google App Engine. Its been going really well until I hit one of their limitations in file size -- 1MB. One of the components of my application resizes images, which have been uploaded by users. The files are directly uploaded to S3 (http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1434) via POST. I was planning on using a CDN to delivered the resized images.

Question:

I was wondering if there was CDN that provided an API for resizing images through HTTP call. I found out that SimpleCDN once provided the service, but has sense removed it. I would like to tell the CDN to resize the image I am requesting from the URL.

For example,

original URL:
http://cdn.example.com/images/large_picture.jpg
resized image to 125x100:
http://cdn.example.com/images/large_picture.jpg/125/100

Does anyone know of CDN that provides a functionality like this? Or have a suggestion to get around the 1MB limit on Google App Engine (not a hack, but alternative method of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I have found a service that provides what I am indeed looking for. [Nirvanix](http://developer.nirvanix.com/files/folders/python/entry1253.aspx) provides an image resize API and even has a nice library for Google App Engine to use with their API. Just thought I would share my findings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Did this work out well for you in the end?

Answer (score 3):

SteadyOffload does it as well.